# Find $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ where $f=h(x+y,y^2,x+z)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

> Find $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ where $f=h(x+y,y^2,x+z)$

I think that the solution is $(1,0,1)$, but I am not sure why that is the case. How am I to compute a partial derivative without a definition for the function f? I know the chain rule, but I don't know why $\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}$ where $u=x+y$ is $(1,0,0)$, as seemed to be the case when my professor did this example.

Comment: For an explicit expression you need the definition of $h$.

Answer (score 1):

You have two functions. First
$$m:\mathbb{R}^{3}\to\mathbb{R}^{3}\\(x,y,z)\mapsto(x+y,y^2,x+z)$$
And then another function
$$h:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$$
for which we don't have an explicit prescription.

Your function $f:\mathbb{R}^{3}\to\mathbb{R}$ is defined as the composition $h\circ m$. Then, by the chainrule, we have
$$\frac{\partial f(x,y,z)}{\partial x} = \sum_{i=1}^{3} \frac{\partial h(a_1,a_2,a_3)}{\partial a_{i}}
\Bigg|_{(a_1,a_2,a_3)=m(x,y,z)}
 \frac{\partial m^{i}(x,y,z)}{\partial x}$$

See if you can continue from there.

Comment: What are the $\partial m^i$?

Comment: It isnt hard for me to get to $\frac{\partial h}{\partial m^1} + \frac{\partial h}{\partial m^3}$. But i cant do anything further, correct?

Comment: @Colebasaur That's correct. Without a prescription for what $h$ does, you cannot  know its derivative.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor $\frac{\partial m^{i}}{\partial x}$ are the derivatives of each of the ouputs the function $m:(x,y,z)\mapsto(x+y,y^2,x+z)$ with respect to its first entry.
I.e., $\frac{\partial m^{1}}{\partial x}=1$, $\frac{\partial m^{2}}{\partial x}=0$, $\frac{\partial m^{3}}{\partial x}=1$.